# Bloomberg - Exporting Value-at-Risk in Excel

Tags: excel, var, bloomberg

I am trying to export the information from the VaR -> Var Comparison tab from the `PORT` function.

Using  the `=BDH()` function in Excel, the arguments `IS_TOTAL_VALUE_AT_RISK`, `ARDR_TOTAL_VALUE_AT_RISK`, yield `#N/A`. Basically, all the arguments including Value-at-Risk in the Bloomberg API importer yield `#N/A`.

Is there any other way to export this data, besides of exporting manually? I need the daily VaR values from several securities, so exporting manually is extremely tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bloomberg Help Desk team has confirmed that there is, for the time being, no way to bulk download the VaR data from the `PORT` function.